# facebook oauth dialog not working in android 2.2(samsung GT-S5830) in a webview and web browser

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-oauth

I am trying to implement facebook Oauth dialog(direct url approach)

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

It works fine at all places except android in samsung GT-S5830 where it stops with the text

window.location.href="REDIRECT URL?code=code

even in the webview as well as in the webbrowser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research, figured out that the problem is when display = 'touch'. It works fine with display='wap'.

But display='wap' has the following disadvantages
1) It always shows the allow access screen(even if the user has allowed the app)
2) Design looks distorted as compared to display=touch